# Can the callback procedure of SetWindowsHookEx() contains a call to a managed code method?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I get this problem only with thread-specific hooks. `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and `WH_MOUSE_LL` work both fine as the dll doesn't have to be injected somewhere. This is one of the callback procedures form the dll:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HookData[WH_KEYBOARD + 1].lpfn(nCode, wParam, lParam);
    return CallNextHookEx(HookData[WH_KEYBOARD + 1].hhook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

`lpfn` is the method from the managed code (C# project) that will marshal and store the parameters for further analisys. When that method is called, the process of the thread I want to monitor crashes for "access violation" (the thread I use to test the hook is that of the window of notepad).

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Value", L"KeyboardHook", MB_OK);
    return CallNextHookEx(HookData[WH_KEYBOARD + 1].hhook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I tried then this way and it worked fine, showing a message box everytime I pressed a key when the window of notepad was focused.

So, is there a way to call that method? Or maybe am I calling that method in a wrong way? If I can't call that method, is there another way to pass the callback parameters to the C# project everytime the callback procedure is called?

Comment: That's not possible, pointers are only valid in the process that created them.  Since you inject the DLL into another process, trying to dereference the pointer always causes a crash.  You cannot call a method in another process directly, regardless whether is is native or managed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you confirmed what I was afraid of. Now i'm wondering if I can do a thread-specific hook in C#

Comment: I've finally accomplished my goal. Instead of passing the pointer of the CallBack method I created a thread with the GetMessage procedure in the C# project that will receive the CallBack params sent by the CallBack procedure itself using the PostThreadMessage procedure. The thread id of the thread where GetMessage is running is retrieved by reading a NamedPipe in wich I wrote that thread id. So far I can set multiple hooks in several threads at the same time, but I feel this way is too tricky.